# How can I run `make` and retrieve the binary from a remote host without `ssh`ing twice?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, sftp

I'm working on a project for which I don't have the toolchain configured on my own machine and I'm thus developing remotely. My workflow right now looks as follows:

- open the remote project directory in my file manager using sftp
- edit some files
- run `make remote`, which connects to the remote machine via ssh and runs `make` there:

  `ssh $(HOST) cd $(DIRECTORY) \; make`
- run `make get`, which transfers the binary via `scp`:

  `scp $(HOST):$(DIRECTORY)/build/$(FILE) .`
- test the binary and repeat

The problem is, the remote machine only does password authentication, so I have to enter the password twice in each cycle. Can't I build and download in the same `ssh` session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think SSH session sharing would be useful in this situation. It allows you to open multiple sessions over a single connection so that you only have to enter your password once. In your .ssh/config:

```
Host *
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
```

So you could open one terminal, SSH into your server, and run your editor. Then you could open another terminal, SSH into the same server using the shared connection, and run make and scp from there. More info:

- http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/ssh-controlmaster/
- http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

Comment: this is the cleanest and most direct solution to the problem I could imagine! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Mount the remote side using sshfs and work 'locally'. After running your remote make, you will see the result in your local mount point without explicitly copying it.

Comment: Together with Roberto's suggestion, this saves me from any password typing! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

while combining the two remote tasks into two sessions may be possible, in this case the sftp mount of the remote file system can be used. Instead of using `scp`, you can use `gvfs-move` for `make get`:

```
gvfs-move sftp://$(HOST)$(REMOTE_HOME)/$(DIRECTORY)/build/$(FILE) .
```

since the mount is already established, it's likely faster than `scp`, even without having to enter the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can insctruct your make command to read your password in one variable, then you can use sshpass to make the two connections..

Something like:

```
read -p "Enter your password: " PASSWORD
sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh user@host 'cd '$(DIRECTORY)' \; make'
sshpass -p $PASSWORD scp $(HOST):$(DIRECTORY)/build/$(FILE) .
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to keep Roberto's answer accepted, but still share what I ended up doing:

First of all, I used Roberto's suggestion to enable session sharing: in `.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
```

Furthermore, I do mount the remote file system using `sshfs` (all in the makefile):

```
mount:
    sshfs $(HOST):$(DIRECTORY) $(MOUNTPOINT)

unmount:
    fusermount -u $(MOUNTPOINT)
```

For the actual building targets:

```
make:
    ssh $(HOST) cd $(DIRECTORY) \; make

clean:
    ssh $(HOST) cd $(DIRECTORY) \; make clean
```

Since `sshfs` keeps an ssh connection open, I don't need to enter the password at all while working, and no special handling in necessary for the binary (which is why I skip the `install` target). The additional upside of having a plain mountpoint is that I can use git as with any ordinary project.